# how to open phpmyadmin tool on browser in ubntu in my pc

Tags: mysql

i am trying to setup phpmyadmin tool on browser in Ubuntu but couldn't find the correct way . currently i use `mysql -u root -p` this command in terminal 
how can i do this

Comment: If you're just getting started with MySQL, I suggest you try MySQL Workbench instead of phpMyAdmin unless you have a reason why you prefer to use a web-based tool.

Answer (score 3):

Really?

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/phpmyadmin.html

EDIT: If your phpmyadmin is only accessible locally, then you can enable the `AllowNoPassword` setting in the `config.inc.php` file in the root of the phpmyadmin install. Just uncomment this line in that file:

`// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;`

Comment: thanks Jaitsu... now i can open phpmyadmin but now i am facing  a problem [Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)] but i use root as username and i didnot give any password at installation  how can i know my credentials?

Comment: I've edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install phpmyadmin (assuming you have MySQL installed). I usually do this by opening up terminal and typing...

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Then, the first thing I see is that I can't access phpmyadmin by typing "http://localhost/phpmyadmin" in my browser. That can be fixed by mounting phpmyadmin to your /var/www folder using the following in terminal...

```
sudo mount --bind /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin
```

Comment: A symlink might be more appropriate than a bind mount for this!